# Constructing a hex array from binary data from serial port

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, pyserial

I have an external device, serially connected to a PC.
Data is binary, not characters, meaning that I should not interpret data as ASCII characters.

In the PC, I have Python 3.7 that reads the serial device with the use of pyserial.
I want to fill a int8 array with the incoming data.

I am working with threads, here is where I am so far, but this is not my first piece of code, I have tried several things, none of which worked.

```py
def get_data(sent, m_serport)
    constr_resp = np.int8([0])
    resp = np.int8([0])
    resp_index = 0

        while (1):
            if (m_serport.in_waiting > 0):
                resp = master_ser.read(1)
                constr_resp = np.concatenate(constr_resp, resp)
                resp_index = resp_index + 1
                parse(constr_resp, resp_index)
```

This one generates the following error:
TypeError: 'bytes' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

I have a somewhat strong C background, and Python is very confusing to me when it comes to data types.

I hope my question is easily understood.

Thanks.

Comment: Using `np.int8([8])` is the same as `np.array([0], dtype=np.int8)`.  I think the latter is more idiomatic numpy.  Not that it makes a difference in this code.  Repeated `concatenate` in a loop is inefficient.  It makes a new array each time.

Comment: If you have a strong C background, I'm a little surprised that you don't give us the traceback or otherwise indicate exactly where the error occurs.  Isn't that a crucial step in debugging?

Comment: The error is in the line with the concatenate. What is a traceback?

Comment: I mean the full error message including the where info.  Sometimes that shows several layers of function calls (though may be not here).  In any case, it's having problems converting your `resp` value to `np.int8` (an integer).

Comment: In Python variables don't have a fixed type; objects assigned to variables have a type.  You first assign a numpy array (1 element, `int8` dtype) to `resp`, but later assign the result of the `read` (a byte).  The initial assignment did nothing for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think getting data should start with building a list of bytes:

```
def get_data(sent, m_serport)
    alist = []
    resp_index = 0
        while (1):
            if (m_serport.in_waiting > 0):
                resp = master_ser.read(1)
                alist.append(resp)
                resp_index += resp_index
                # parse(alist, resp_index)
    return alist
```

You may not need `resp_index` since it should just be `len(alist)`.  Also I don't think you want the `parse` in this loop, but I don't know what it's supposed to be doing.

Comment: Thanks I will try this. Why do you think I should not parse in the loop?

Comment: It worked, how do I write that this answer solved it?

Answer (score 0):

Kostbil, using python to access external data can be a little tricky but trust me, it's no big deal. In this case, debugging might be easier if you know what line the error is...
You could also use print() to debug.

In my opinion, you could call the decode method i.e .decode() on the data you're getting externally before performing any integer operation. say, externalData.decode()

Hope this works.

Comment: I will try the decode. My main frustration is that, in C, this would be very natural, but in Python, it is very difficult to find out how to do it, and furthermore, it is probably time consuming.

Comment: Kostbil, I would like to know what finally worked for you.

Comment: Well, I had some problems overall, I still don't understand how it works, just that it works. The one thing that helps for sure is that I declared my variables as np.int8([0]). Do you have the same problems?

Comment: No, I don't. Good something worked for you. The code by hPaulj is very pythonic